# Cannot duplicate column to embulk output with "embulk-filter-column"

Tags: mysql, google-bigquery

I want to copy a column with the same contents as a specific column in mysql by embulk.
The filter plugin "embulk-filter-column" doesn't work well and I can't copy.

The cause and solution could not be extracted from the log.
What do you think is wrong?
Please point out grammatical mistakes.

bq.yml.requid

```
in:
  type: mysql
  host:  {{ env.HOST }}
  user: {{ env.USER }}
  password: {{ env.PASS }}
  database: {{ env.DB }}

filter:
  - type: column
    columns:
      - {name: DATA_COPY, src: DATE}

out:
  type: bigquery
  mode: replace
  auth_method: json_key
  json_keyfile: '{{ env.CREDENTIAL }}'
  path_prefix: tmp
  allow_quoted_newlines: 1 #
  file_ext: .csv.gz
  source_format: CSV
  project: {{ env.PROJECT }}
  dataset: {{ env.DATASET }}
  auto_create_table: true
  table: {{ env.TABLE }}
  formatter: {type: csv, charset: UTF-8, delimiter: ',', header_line: false}
  encoders:
  - {type: gzip}
```

IN

```
ID,DATE
1,2021-11-12
```

OUT

```
ID,DATE
1,2021-11-12T00:00:00
```

Answer (score 1):

indent miss

```
filters:
- type: column
  add_columns:
  - {name: DATA_COPY, src: DATE}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the configuration is OK.

Have you ever tried `bq.yml.liquid` instead of `bq.yml.requid`?
And Could you paste the error message?

I tested the following configuration. It added `filters` parts into the configuration file of `embulk example`.

```yaml
in:
  type: file
  path_prefix: path/to/csv/sample_
  decoders:
  - {type: gzip}
  parser:
    charset: UTF-8
    newline: LF
    type: csv
    delimiter: ','
    quote: '"'
    escape: '"'
    null_string: 'NULL'
    trim_if_not_quoted: false
    skip_header_lines: 1
    allow_extra_columns: false
    allow_optional_columns: false
    columns:
    - {name: id, type: long}
    - {name: account, type: long}
    - {name: time, type: timestamp, format: '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'}
    - {name: purchase, type: timestamp, format: '%Y%m%d'}
    - {name: comment, type: string}
out: {type: stdout}

filters:
- type: column
  add_columns:
  - {name: account_copy, src: account}
```